# Calculating an angle relative to a reference line

Tags: geometry

[PLEASE SEE PICTURE -angle relative to baseline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjNYT.jpg)we've been struggling with this for a while. Assuming we have distance between our measurement point P0 and P3-P4 and as also between P0 and our reference line P1-p2. Can we calculate the angle of p3-p4 relative to p1-p2? Once we figure this out, we'll see our to program it for IOS. Thanks for anyone who can point me in the right direction. [PLEASE SEE PICTURE relative angle measurement][2]

Comment: Probably more a question for math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: And I don't think you can calculate the angle between two lines, if all you know is the distance of the lines to a point (maybe I'm just confused by your notation, though).

Comment: Please specify what distances exactly you know. If distances  from point P0 to lines (length of perpendicular from point to line), then it is impossible to find angle (imagine that P3P4 rotates about P0)

Answer (score 0):

If P0 is a known point and P1-P2 and P3-P4 are defined lines in a 2D coordinate system (ie P0 to each line a defined vector)  then you can certainly calculate the angle between the two lines.   However if all you know is distance from P0 to each line as a function of a point on either line then you cannot calculate the angle distance alone will not give you what you need without some point of reference.

Comment: Thank you Rob! I appreciate you take the time to help me figure this out. Actually I was wondering if with a laser measurement tool or other type of sensor if I could measure the distance to the different points from P0 and then use some formula to derive the angle relative to the reference line.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is impossible as you have described.  Distance is a scalar quantity and although you may have a continuous distance measurement you can not determine direction from this.  A simple model would be two different yet symmetrical lines (with respect to a line passing through P0) would provide identical distance measurements but obviously have different relative angles with respect to another line.  You simply need a way to define distance as a vector and your problem then becomes trivial.  I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Also keep in mind that my answer is a general truth of mathematics based on how your question is worded.  If there are geometric constraints that can be included in your diagram, that can allow us to assume known geometric relationships then we may have something to work with.